# Even simplest postresql query takes ages in a big table with indexes

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, google-cloud-platform, query-performance

I have a problem with a very slow query execution in my psql table which has `145 602 995` rows (yep 145+ millions). I have indexes created but even simplest query takes ages to execute... For example query like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM events;` takes 708 seconds (~12 minutes).

I have a column called `org_id` which has an index and when I try to execute query like:

`EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT COUNT(*) FROM events WHERE org_id = 1;`

```
Aggregate  (cost=8191.76..8191.77 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=9.758..9.758 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Index Only Scan using org_id on events  (cost=0.57..8179.63 rows=4853 width=0) (actual time=1.172..9.729 rows=48 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (org_id = 1)
        Heap Fetches: 48
Planning time: 0.167 ms
Execution time: 9.803 ms
```

it's using the `org_id` index but estimated cost was huge.

As I increase `org_id` number I get slower and slower execution times. It's probably related with less records for the `org_id`s with smaller numbers. When I get to `org_id = 9` where there are a lot of records it stops using the `org_id` index and uses `Bitmap Heap Scan` and `Bitmap Index Scan` instead.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(*) FROM events WHERE org_id = 9;
```

```
Aggregate  (cost=10834654.32..10834654.33 rows=1 width=8)
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on events  (cost=147380.56..10814983.35 rows=7868386 width=0)
        Recheck Cond: (org_id = 9)
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on org_id  (cost=0.00..145413.46 rows=7868386 width=0)
              Index Cond: (org_id = 9)
```

Is there any way of improving speed with such a big tables? One extra info is that I have 11 columns in this table where one of them is of the `jsonb NOT NULL` type. Just mentioning. Maybe it's important.

EDIT:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM events;
```

```
Aggregate  (cost=12873195.66..12873195.67 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=653255.247..653255.248 rows=1 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=292755 read=10754192
  ->  Seq Scan on events  (cost=0.00..12507945.93 rows=146099893 width=0) (actual time=0.015..638846.285 rows=146318426 loops=1)
        Buffers: shared hit=292755 read=10754192
Planning time: 0.215 ms
Execution time: 653255.315 ms
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers)`** for a **slow** execution.

Comment: Shot in the dark here, but does trying something like `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM ....` instead of `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...` behave any differently?  That's an old bug in Postgres and I'm pretty sure it's been fixed for a long time, but worth a shot.

Comment: @sovemp yep executing `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM events;` takes ages too. Btw. we're using the postgresql version 9.6.6.
@a_horse_with_no_name I will execute query and update my question in around 12 minute when it finishes calculating :P

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ok I've updated my question to reflect EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)

Comment: @sovemp: that was never a bug in Postgres. `count(*)` and `count(1)` always behaved the same

Comment: So reading 82GB took around 11 seconds. That's a throughput of approx. 140MB/Second. That sounds like a really slow harddisk. I am not sure if tuple-deforming comes into play here, people with more insights into Postgres would need to answer that. I am surprised that Postgres didn't choose a Parallel Seq Scan for this. What is the setting of `max_parallel_workers_per_gather` and `max_parallel_workers`? What kind of harddisk or I/O system does your server have? Upgrading to Postgres 11 will most probably also improve performance

Comment: 0) add the relevant DDL, (and some metrics) 1) `vacuum analyze` 2) `postgres.conf` tuning constants?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name We're using Google Cloud SQL storage. We have 2 vCPU's, 7.5 GB of memory and SSD storage.
`max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 0`
`ERROR: unrecognized configuration parameter "max_parallel_workers"`
We can't upgrade to Postgres 11 because gcloud only offers version 9.6

Comment: @wildplasser could you elaborate more on what you said? What exactly do I have to do?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/18486/134289

Comment: @wildplasser how could changing those constants help in query analyzer picking the right way to execute query?

Comment: First:understand your query. Next: what is the selectivity of the condition? what is the cardinality of `org_id' ? Which records do you assume to be present  in buffers/cache? [BTW: a `count(*)` query ] is relatively useless. in your case, it only measures your I/O bandwith]